# Numpy array, power operator, wrong value/sign

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

When I execute the below on Ipython:

```
test = np.array([1,2,3,4])
test**50
```

it returns:

```
array([          1, -2147483648, -2147483648, -2147483648])
```

which has both the wrong value and sign. Any clues why I might be getting this?

Comment: Numpy integer numbers have limited range. When you get a very large number (e.g., `2**50`), it "wraps around" and becomes negative. This phenomenon is called overflow. Unlike Numpy, Python itself does not have this limitation: `4**50` is  1267650600228229401496703205376.

Comment: @DYZ ... to be more precise the Numpy types are, as you say, constrained for efficiency (and many are signed types, as you say).  But Python's native integer objects will be automatically promoted into large integer objects to prevent overflow. Specifically the `np.array()` constructor will set the dtype to the minimal sized type which can handle the initial values provided.  You can used a keyword argument (option) `dtype=` to over-ride this or to "upcast" the types.  `test = np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype='int')` should work better. But still might not handle this extreme.

Comment: (Specifically when I tested this example witih Python 2.7.17 and Numpy 1.11.1 I get the auto-promotion to large integer and all is, apparently, fine up to about `test**31` ... but beyond that the operation causes: *RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power*).  So the Numpy broadcast of such large exponentiations isn't necessary completely transparent as compared to the same operations on native Python large integers). https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this happens because the integer data type overflows. Numpy initializes the array with a low level `int` data type because that fits the data you provided.

```
test = np.array([1,2,3,4])
test.dtype
# dtype('int32')

test[0] = 2**31 - 1  # works
test[0] = 2**31      # OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

A 32 bit signed integer is used (on my system), which can hold values between -2147483648 and 2147483647.

You can force the array to have a different data type, e.g. floating point:

```
test = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=float)
# test = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])  # this is the same
test**50

# array([  1.00000000e+00,   1.12589991e+15,   7.17897988e+23, 1.26765060e+30])
```

Here is a [list of data types](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) that can be passed as strings to the `dtype` argument.

If you want Python's large integers instead of floating point precision, this works too (*performance warning*):

```
test = np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype=object)
test**50

# array([1, 1125899906842624, 717897987691852588770249, 
#        1267650600228229401496703205376], dtype=object)
```