# Jupyter notebook code returning different plots on different devices

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Code to generate a simple plot (below) runs on my jupyter notebook with no issue, and produces the expected figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsfcH.png). But another individual running the same code on their computer (after clearing the kernel) gets a plot that looks completely different [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvwgE.png). Is there some user error (in running the code) that would cause this?

We are both using the anaconda distribution for python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sigma = 5.67e-8 #stefan boltzman constant in W/(m^2)/(K^4)
T = np.arange(50,800,) #units in K
F = sigma*T**4 #Flux in units of W/m/m

T1 = 289 #Temperature of the earth in K
T2 = 698 #Temperature of venus in K
T3 = 210 #Temperature of mars in K
T4 = 90 #Temperature of titan in K

T_p = np.array([T1, T2, T3, T4]) #array of planetary surface temperatures
F_p = sigma*T_p**4
             
print(F_p)

plt.plot(T,F) #plot Stefan-Boltzman law for T = 50 to 800K
plt.plot(T_p[0], F_p[0], 'o', label='Earth', color='red')
plt.plot(T_p[1], F_p[1], 'o', label='Venus', color='blue')
plt.plot(T_p[2], F_p[2], 'o', label='Mars', color='green')
plt.plot(T_p[3], F_p[3], 'o', label='Titan', color='purple')

plt.xlabel('Temperature of planetary surface, T (K)')
plt.ylabel('Flux, F (W/m$^{2})$')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Stefan-Boltzman law')
```

Comment: those two are completely different.... I printed out the points that you plotted and those are: ``289 -91.5238444617 Earth``, ``698 64.8952102512 Venus``, ``210 110.270727 Mars``, ``90 3.720087 Titan``.

Comment: Your plot number 2 is the correct one. Number 1 can't be correct, I printed ``F_p`` and it is ``F_p = 
[-91.52384446  64.89521025 110.270727     3.720087  ]``

Comment: you are right, I didn't check the math... my bad. I didn't compute the values, OP did. I wonder why ``F_p = sigma*T_p**4`` gives out a wrong computation...

Comment: Found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690524/numpy-array-power-operator-wrong-value-sign

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny it just need some minor corrections, also missing ``fig, ax = plt.subplots()``, other than those two, it works

Comment: Thank you for the responses, and for pointing out the overflow issue. However, I don't quite understand why this would affect one person running a notebook and not someone else running the same notebook on another device. This might be related, but I also cannot get the F_p outputs that @Karina finds in their second comment. Mine are always F_p = [ 395.5254469047 13458.750722827199  110.270727 3.720087 ]

Comment: that's not the correct number either what you have there. As I said before, the problem is number overflow caused by numpy. As to why it's different in your machine or in my machine, it could be that I somehow somewhere set the default limit myself (which I don't remember anymore).

Comment: You might be able to overcome this problem by not using numpy, just use pure python: https://mortada.net/can-integer-operations-overflow-in-python.html